# How to append command output to MariaDB database?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, mariadb

How can I append the output of Linux shell commands to a MariaDB database?

I'm not an SQL expert nor a shell scripting guru, I do understand how databases work and know my way around the Linux shell for basic stuff as well as basic SQL queries, but this is something beyond my knowledge that I need to achieve.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are the shell commands generating SQL statements?  If so:

```
your_script | mysql -uuser -ppwd
```